# add and remove a class list based on another div is display none or block

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="modal fade modal-s" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false"
                    tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
           content..............
                </div>
```

by using javascript this div is going display none and block

i want when this div is display block i wiil add a class list to another div and when the none i will remove the class

i have tried this but didnt work the div with id 'over-lap' i want to add and remove class from that

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var mod = document.querySelector('.modal-s');
  var overLapDiv = document.getElementById('over-lap');
  if (mod.style.display == 'none') {
    overLapDiv.classList.remove('overlap-div'); // Fixed typo
  } else if (mod.style.display == 'block'){
    overLapDiv.classList.add('overlap-div');
  }
});
```

other logic i tried

```
<body>
  <div class="modal-s show">...</div>
  <div id="over-lap"></div>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var mod = document.querySelector('.modal-s');
      var overLapDiv = document.getElementById('over-lap');
      if (mod.classList.contains('show')) {
        overLapDiv.classList.add('overlap-div');
      } else {
        overLapDiv.classList.remove('overlap-div');
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `mod.style.display` is empty. You need to use `window.getComputedStyle(mod, null).display`. Example:

```js
const mod = document.querySelector('.modal-s');
  
console.log(mod.style.display); // empty
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(mod, null).display); // 'block'
```

```html
<div class="modal-s show">...</div>
<div id="over-lap"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//do not use this in if-condition it won't work.
//mod.style.display == 'none'


//make class d-none or any classname so, that it can remove or add

//removing d-none will show div & adding this d-none class will hide the element.

//use classlist.contains
if(mod.classlist.contains("d-none")){
}


//to remove class from classlist
mod.classlist.remove("d-none")

//to add class from classlist
mod.classlist.add("d-none")


//there is also toggling (if class is present then it will remove and if not present then add on each event provided)
mod.classlist.toggle("d-none");
```

```css
.d-none{
  display:none;
}
```